# Spring Security and Spring Session use different cookies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I was using Spring Security with this configuration:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
  http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
```

Using that configuration every request received a `JSESSIONID` cookie.

I started using Spring Session (backed by redis) using `@EnableRedisHttpSession` and now client is receiving previous `JSESSIONID` cookie and also a new cookie called `SESSION`.

I expect both Spring Security and Spring Session to use the same cookie.

Which configuration changes do I have to make?

Thanks in advance.